# Is Camunda 7.13 compatible with Postgres 12.4?

Tags: postgresql, camunda

We’re using Camunda 7.13 and want to upgrade the PostgreSQL version from 10.x to 12.x.

I found documentation that says Camunda 7.13 has support for PostgreSQL 12.2.

For unrelated reasons, I am not able to upgrade PostgreSQL to 12.2 but I could target 12.4 or 12.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Camunda 7.14 onwards the documentation does not differentiate PostgreSQL minor versions anymore. It simply states:

> PostgreSQL 9.4 / 9.6 / 10 / 11 / 12

(https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.14/introduction/supported-environments/)
or later:

> PostgreSQL 12 / 13 / 14 / 15

(https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.19/introduction/supported-environments/)
This is a strong indicator that there were no relevant changes in the PostgreSQL minor versions.

I can't write this answer without pointing out that Camunda 7.13 is >6 years old and a long number of security relevant fixes such as the famous [log4shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4Shell) vulnerability have been addressed in that time (https://docs.camunda.org/security/notices/). It is very easy to upgrade between Camunda 7.x minor versions as they always remain backwards compatible. Only having to upgrade the Spring version (if that is your deployment type) may be a consideration. If your 7.13 is already using Spring 2.3.x.RELEASE, then you can upgrade to at least Camunda 7.14.20 without changing the Spring version (https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.19/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/version-compatibility/). On 7.14.20 you also get official PostgreSQL 12.x support.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.timescale.com/blog/read-before-you-upgrade-best-practices-for-choosing-your-postgresql-version/#:%7E:text=are%20always%20backward%20compatible%20with%20the%20major%20version) Minor versions of PostgreSQL (e.g., from PostgreSQL 13 to PostgreSQL 13.2) are always backward compatible with the major version. That means that Camunda 7.13 should be compatible (in theory) with PostgreSQL 12.4 or 12.6